# PHP $_POST empty when passing data through Android

Tags: php, android, json

I'm trying to pass data from Android to my PHP application, but it seems to POST method is not working well, once all $_POST variables are empty.

Part of my Android activity:

```
String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
String name = inputName.getText().toString();
String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
String date  = inputDate.getText().toString();

// Building Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));

// Getting JSON Object
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
```

Now, on my JSONParser.java:

```
 // check for request method
 if(method == "POST"){
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    Log.v("response code", httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ""); 
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

I've omitted non-relevant parts of the code, because I actually reach the server, only getting empty $_POST variables.

A curious thing, if I delete this line...

```
httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
```

... the request doesn't work at all.

I'm following this tutorial: [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

I would be very glad if someone could help me!

Comment: `all $_POST variables are empty`, the `$_POST` variable is filled when the request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `application/json`

Comment: So how can I fix this? If I change to: httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") I receive the famous error: "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0". Thanks in advance.

Comment: But you would still be sending json wouldn't you?

Comment: could you post the JSON response of the call? maybe it's broken somehow

Comment: @Musa, if I put both httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json") and httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") I got the same errors (no $_POST).

Comment: @lelloman, i don't think it's broken. Actually, I'm getting this json http://rafael.daniels1006.webfactional.com/users/addUser. Obviously every `$_POST` param is null because nothing is set, but this shouldn't occur when accessibg through Android.

Comment: are you sure you're getting the same string with android? this one seems to be ok

Comment: Yep. When I use the code in OP, everything works well (except, of course, `$_POST` params) and I can handle whenever I got.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
// Getting JSON Object
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url, nameValuePairs);
```

`JSONfunctions` class

```
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    InputStream is = getData(url, nameValuePairs);
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;
    // convert response to string
    try {
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        int intch;
        while ((intch = r.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) intch;
            // Log.i("app", Character.toString(ch));
            String s = new String(Character.toString(ch).getBytes(), "UTF-8");
            sb.append(s);
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.i("JSON", result);
        jArray = new JSONObject(result);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());

    }
    return jArray;
}


public static InputStream getData(String Url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in http connection " + e.getMessage().toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in http connection " + e.getMessage().toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in http connection " + e.getMessage().toString());

    }
    return is;

}
```

Your PHP Code

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $date = $_POST['date'];
```

Comment: Had to do some adaptations, for example `params` was a `List<NameValuePair>`and not a `ArrayList<NameValuePair>`. Nevertheless, got `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0` again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually without `httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")` I can't reach the server. When using your functions, it seems to not reach as well. You can check my JSON in http://rafael.daniels1006.webfactional.com/users/addUser. Obviously every `$_POST` param is null because nothing is set, but this shouldn't occur when accessing through Android.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve the problem.
PhpMyAdmin configurations were incorrect and then I was trying to parse something that wasn't a JSON object.

Now there's no need of `httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");`, as @Musa smartly observed. Thank you all for responses.